# Re-Calibrate Android Compass

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5x, calibration, compass

I have a Nexus 5X and was in a bit of a hurry when I followed the setup steps. There was a calibrate compass wizard, which I skipped because I wanted to do this later.

However, I've not figured out yet how to launch the compass calibration wizard again. I found [this question on Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10145/how-can-i-calibrate-the-compass-on-my-phone) telling about the general process, as well as [this Google support article](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6145351), but I couldn't figure out how to launch that wizard again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your phone is aligning you on the maps with the right direction, it should be fine. I've noticed that the wizard coms up automatically once in awhile, (roughly more like once a week) on my 6P. You could try clearing the cache on the maps, but this is not a sure shot way for the wizard to show up.

**Issue resolved by following google recommendation after opening the app (wizard popup was not mandatory)**

Comment: I cleared the cache and I had to accept the Terms and Conditions again, but the wizard didn't come up.

The compass is still pointing about 90° clockwise in the wrong direction which is very annoying.

Comment: Google's official answer does not mention the dependancy on the wizard appearing. Have you tried following the steps after opening maps?

Comment: As I mentioned: I cleared the cache and opened google maps again. The only thing that came up is Terms and Conditions. No further steps

Comment: Oh no, I think you have me confused. What I meant in my earlier comment is  - The wizard need not appear and ask you to recalibrate. You should be able to proceed with flipping your phone vertical, horizontal as soon as you open the app. You may also try certain compass calibration apps available in the market that might help fix the issue.

Comment: Ah okay got it! Well I now opened google maps and simply started doing the recommended moves without launching any wizard or so and it did do the trick. No need to clear the map cache.