# Huawei P7 Ascend Lollipop Compass pointing only North or South, even after calibrating. How to fix?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, huawei, compass

As it says in the title, my Huawei P7 Ascend running the latest firmware for it (Android 5.1.1) has something strange going on with the compass for the last year or so. I have already attempted calibration, but that did not fix it. The compass only exclusively points directly north or directly south, both on calibration apps and in apps like Google Maps. How can I get it to work properly again?

Comment: Wait what? Give us some screenshots or even beter a video?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calibrate the compass on my phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10145/how-can-i-calibrate-the-compass-on-my-phone)

Comment: As stated in the question, I already calibrated it to no avail. I can't take a video because I don't have a camera besides my phone. I can, however describe it: If the phone is facing more towards north, any compass or app will show it facing fully north. Same goes for south. There is no in between.

Answer (score -1):

I too have this problem after upgrading my phone to lollipop. However, if I tilt my phone vertically or upside down (so I'm looking up to face the screen), the compass works fine. Try calibrating your accelerometer with your phone upside down.