# How to disable Google Map's direction indicator?

Tags: google-maps

Where the indicator wouldn't be accurate, having it is just noise; Is there a way to stop it from showing?

---

- The indicator:

[image]

Comment: Normally one would recalibrate the compass like: [How can I calibrate the compass on my phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/10145/3573)

Comment: @MorrisonChang, Problems with some locations.