# Google maps compass breaks when using underground public transport

Tags: google-maps, compass

Suppose I took a U-bahn/Metro/Subway. After the ride finishes, the exit the station and get back to ground level.

Now I notice that the compass in Google Maps always points to a random direction as north, which is usually not correct.

If I use any other compass app in my phone, they point the north correctly.

Is it possible to fix the Google Maps?

Comment: Unclear if you tried [recalibrating the compass](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/10145/3573) in Google Maps or when you close Google Maps to make sure Google Maps is stopped before restarting (as other compass apps seems to work fine).