Google maps walking navigation has wrong orientation
I'm using Google Maps on my Pixel 8a to while I'm driving and it works nicely.
But the map interface is all messed up when I'm using it in walking mode. If I let the app adjust the perspective itself, the arrow starts pointing towards a random direction and the path is usually hidden out of view. This is what I see unless I  fix perspective by panning and rotating every 10 meters or so.
To clarify: Google Maps shows my location and the direction I am heading correctly. It just doesn't rotate it's view so that the arrow is pointing upwards.

Here's what I (and probably everyone else) expect it to look like:

Is this a bug with Google Maps or should I be change some setting?

The orientation is usually done using the electronic compass. This component works only with acceptable precision if you calibrate it. Calibration is AFIR even possible from within Google Maps.

Hello Robert, I clarified my answer. I think my compass works well (it shows the correct heading and position). That said, I'd appreciate if you could explain how I can calibrate the compass.

Please see https://android.stackexchange.com/a/10148/2241 Keep in mind that the compass works by magnetism. Therefore large magnetic objects around you may temporary confuse the compass. Therefore the orientation problems are location specific then the problem may be located outside of your phone.

In certain situations, such as cloudy skies, narrow streets with tall buildings, or other obstructions, GPS accuracy may be compromised, leading to less precise positioning or delayed updates. However, given the consistent nature of the issue, I suspect it's more likely a software bug than a connection problem. Please try updating the app to the latest version and testing again. If the problem persists, utilizing the web version of Google Maps can help isolate whether the issue lies with the app or your device's GPS hardware.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
